# Define select with optgroup via input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, html, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following select:

```
= f.select(:city, grouped_options_for_select([["USA", ["Alabama", "Alaska"]], ["Canada", ["Ontario", "Quebec"]]]))
```

This is what I need. But not exactly. Due to the specific css styles I'd like to define it via input. But this doesn't work as I expect (and I want it to be the same at the above example):

```
= f.input(:city, collection: [["USA", ["Alabama", "Alaska"]], ["Canada", ["Ontario", "Quebec"]]])
```

The key here is that I'd like to use `f.input` (and the parameter `collection`) to do the same thing as I've done via `f.select`. Is it possible?

Comment: You said `specific css styles`.What `styles` exactly? You can pass a css `style` with `:style` in `select` though.

Comment: `f.input`. that's `simple_form`. correct?

Comment: Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837416/ruby-on-rails-dropdown-select-menu-how-to-style-or-apply-class-to-the-option

Comment: @Pavan, you should re-read my question. The question is how to do that using "input" method.

Comment: Ofcourse I've read! If there is a way with `select` why to use `input`?And also i'm talking about `select` not `input`

Comment: @Pavan, wait a moment, you might be right.

Comment: Did it worked for you?

Comment: @Pavan, actually I didn't try it but I found out what was the cause - simple_form. Thanks.

Comment: Hmm, glad you found it :)